# Alert dialog not dismiss when application goes background in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I used the following code:

```
Alertdialog alertDialog =null;
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        alertDialog=builder.create();
        builder.create().show();
```

When I click home key(without any user event in "OK" button) I dismiss the alert dialog using the following code:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {

            if(alertDialog != null){
               alertDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }

        super.onPause();
    }
```

When re launch the application the alert dialog won't disappear.

What I did wrong?

Comment: I don't want to show alert dialog when launch activity.i want to dismiss.

Comment: you have tried same code in onCreate instead of onPause?

Comment: How can we do alert dismiss in Oncreate()?Because when we re launch application after click home key OnStart() method only called.I used dismiss method in OnStart() won't get my result.

Comment: onresume also called when ur application came back to front from bg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you created two AlertDialog instances here:

```
alertDialog=builder.create();
builder.create().show();
```

Then you called dismiss() on the dialog that is not actually shown.
This should fix the problem:

```
alertDialog=builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I called dismiss() in onPause() but it did not work because I set the variable as **static**.

This was resolved when I removed the **static** word...